# Replace dynamic part of a string in update query in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column for rate information.

It has values like:

```
2250.0 - 2300.0 USD Flat  
0.0 - 12.0 AUD per MILE
```

I want to replace the sub-string which appears before currency. Rest string should remain as it is.
For e.g.,
`0.0 - 12.0 AUD per MILE` should become `15.0 AUD per MILE`.
`2250.0 - 2300.0 USD Flat` should become `2500.0 USD Flat`.

Problem is, currency is not same for all records. So I cannot put some logic like find 'USD' and replace sub-string before it with some other string.

Comment: ??  Where did the `15.0` come from in your first desired output, and where did `2500.0` come from in the second one?

Comment: Other logic will take care of those values. We need not worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace the pair of decimals at the start of the string with a single new value while keeping the end of the string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         rate_information,
         '^(\d+\.\d+ - \d+\.\d+)(.*)$',
         TO_CHAR( new_value, 'FM9999999990.0' ) || '\2'
       )
FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: Can you please break down and explain this part:
REGEXP_REPLACE(
         rate_information,
         '^(\d+\.\d+ - \d+\.\d+)(.*)$',
         TO_CHAR( new_value, 'FM9999999990.0' ) || '\2'
       )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the records will always start with digits (the part you want to replace) below query should be doing your job :-

```
select regexp_replace('15.00 - 12.98 USD FLAT','^[\d.\s-]+','Hello ') from dual;
```